# R Lookup values of a column defined by another column's values in mutate()

Tags: r

I am trying to lookup values from other columns in my data frame/tibble that are dependent on the value in column *var*. I can achieve this by hardcoding them in `case_when()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
ds <- tibble(var = paste0("x", sample(1:3, 10, replace = T)),
             x1 = 0:9,
             x2 = 100:109,
             x3 = 1000:1009)
ds %>% 
   mutate(result = case_when(var == "x1" ~ x1,
                             var == "x2" ~ x2,
                             var == "x3" ~ x3))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    var      x1    x2    x3 result
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1 x1        0   100  1000      0
#>  2 x3        1   101  1001   1001
#>  3 x1        2   102  1002      2
#>  4 x2        3   103  1003    103
#>  5 x1        4   104  1004      4
#>  6 x3        5   105  1005   1005
#>  7 x3        6   106  1006   1006
#>  8 x2        7   107  1007    107
#>  9 x2        8   108  1008    108
#> 10 x3        9   109  1009   1009
```

However, What if I don't have just 3 columns but many *xn*?
I found that the following works for an external variable/object:

```r
y <- "x2"
ds %>% 
  mutate(result = !!sym(y))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    var      x1    x2    x3 result
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1 x1        0   100  1000    100
#>  2 x3        1   101  1001    101
#>  3 x1        2   102  1002    102
#>  4 x2        3   103  1003    103
#>  5 x1        4   104  1004    104
#>  6 x3        5   105  1005    105
#>  7 x3        6   106  1006    106
#>  8 x2        7   107  1007    107
#>  9 x2        8   108  1008    108
#> 10 x3        9   109  1009    109
```

But it doesn't work for an internal variable/column in a tibble:

```r
ds %>% 
  mutate(result = !!sym(var))
#> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
Any ideas of how to get this to work within a data frame/tibble column are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using {dplyr}

There are two solutions I can think of. The first is syntactically a bit cleaner and uses `rowwise()` along with `get()`:

```
ds %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(result = get(var)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    var      x1    x2    x3 result
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1 x1        0   100  1000      0
#>  2 x3        1   101  1001   1001
#>  3 x1        2   102  1002      2
#>  4 x2        3   103  1003    103
#>  5 x1        4   104  1004      4
#>  6 x3        5   105  1005   1005
#>  7 x3        6   106  1006   1006
#>  8 x2        7   107  1007    107
#>  9 x2        8   108  1008    108
#> 10 x3        9   109  1009   1009
```

## Using {purrr}

The second uses `purrr::pmap()` so could be considered a bit more advanced. However it has the advantages of being somewhat faster and more concise:

```
ds %>% 
  mutate(result = pmap_int(., function(var, ...) c(...)[var]))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    var      x1    x2    x3 result
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1 x1        0   100  1000      0
#>  2 x3        1   101  1001   1001
#>  3 x1        2   102  1002      2
#>  4 x2        3   103  1003    103
#>  5 x1        4   104  1004      4
#>  6 x3        5   105  1005   1005
#>  7 x3        6   106  1006   1006
#>  8 x2        7   107  1007    107
#>  9 x2        8   108  1008    108
#> 10 x3        9   109  1009   1009
```

## Edit: A functional approach

One other option I just thought of is to programatically construct a call to `case_when()`. This might look something like the following:

```
# Define a function to construct a `case_when()` call:
x <- switch_cols <- function(var) {
  
  vals <- unique(var)
  
  name <- deparse(substitute(var))
  
  formulae <- lapply(
    sprintf("%s == '%s' ~ %s", name, vals, vals), 
    as.formula, 
    env = parent.frame()
  )
  
  case_when(!!!formulae)
  
}

ds %>% 
    mutate(result = switch_cols(var))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    var      x1    x2    x3 result
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1 x1        0   100  1000      0
#>  2 x3        1   101  1001   1001
#>  3 x1        2   102  1002      2
#>  4 x2        3   103  1003    103
#>  5 x1        4   104  1004      4
#>  6 x3        5   105  1005   1005
#>  7 x3        6   106  1006   1006
#>  8 x2        7   107  1007    107
#>  9 x2        8   108  1008    108
#> 10 x3        9   109  1009   1009
```

## Performance

We can test the performance using `microbenchmark()`. I've also included @akrun's base R solution for completeness:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  
  rowwise = ds %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(result = get(var)) %>% 
    ungroup(),
  
  purrr = ds %>% 
    mutate(result = purrr::pmap_int(., function(var, ...) c(...)[var])),
  
  functional = ds %>% 
    mutate(result = switch_cols(var)),
  
  base1 = ds %>%
    mutate(result = as.data.frame(.[-1])[cbind(dplyr::row_number(), 
                                               match(var, names(.)[-1]))]),
  
  base2 = ds$result <- as.data.frame(ds[-1])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(ds)), 
                                                   match(ds$var, names(ds)[-1]))]
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr    min     lq    mean median      uq   max neval
#>    rowwise 5385.9 6347.3 10692.3 8127.9 12756.3 32893   100
#>      purrr 2957.2 3698.2  5837.4 4533.2  7566.6 12317   100
#> functional 3098.4 3956.6  5625.8 4536.0  7124.5 12665   100
#>      base1 3028.9 3867.3  5839.6 4525.5  7610.0 16408   100
#>      base2  275.9  386.6   584.5  488.6   676.9  3996   100
```

Unsurprisingly, the 'pure' `base R` approach is far-and-away the fastest option. The others are fairly comparable, except for `rowwise()` which is a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think about the combination of `rowwise()` with `get()`

Comment: No problem! It would be nice if there was a solution using `mget()` to avoid using `rowwise()` but unfortunately I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Thanks @wurli for adding the benchmarking. I've been using a solution in base R and was about to spend an hour or two trying alternatives. You've saved my morning being wasted. Peace.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much faster with a row/column indexing approach in `base R`

```
ds$result <- as.data.frame(ds[-1])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(ds)), 
       match(ds$var, names(ds)[-1]))]
ds$result
#[1]    0 1001    2  103    4 1005 1006  107  108 1009
```

---

Or the same in `dplyr` construct`

```
ds %>%
    mutate(result = as.data.frame(.[-1])[cbind(row_number(), 
         match(var, names(.)[-1]))])
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#   var      x1    x2    x3 result
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
# 1 x1        0   100  1000      0
# 2 x3        1   101  1001   1001
# 3 x1        2   102  1002      2
# 4 x2        3   103  1003    103
# 5 x1        4   104  1004      4
# 6 x3        5   105  1005   1005
# 7 x3        6   106  1006   1006
# 8 x2        7   107  1007    107
# 9 x2        8   108  1008    108
#10 x3        9   109  1009   1009
```

Comment: Nice! Yep, about ~5% the time taken by either of my solutions. If speed is a priority, I'd say use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is another very similar solution to one already posted here. You can also use `get` function in combination with function `glue` of package glue:

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

ds %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = get(glue({var})))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Rowwise: 
   var      x1    x2    x3 result
   <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1 x1        0   100  1000      0
 2 x3        1   101  1001   1001
 3 x1        2   102  1002      2
 4 x2        3   103  1003    103
 5 x1        4   104  1004      4
 6 x3        5   105  1005   1005
 7 x3        6   106  1006   1006
 8 x2        7   107  1007    107
 9 x2        8   108  1008    108
10 x3        9   109  1009   1009
```

Whatever you put between double braces in a call to function `glue` will be evaluated as R code.

Comment: Nice option with `glue`

Comment: Thank you very much. At first it sounded one extra step given we could achieve the same result with `get` and `var`. But I've used it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider an alternative tidyverse solution using `pivot_longer()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ds %>%
  pivot_longer(-var) %>%
  filter(var == name) %>%
  bind_cols(ds) %>%
  select(-name, -var...4, 'var' = 'var...1', 'result' = 'value')

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    var   result    x1    x2    x3
#    <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1 x1         0     0   100  1000
#  2 x3      1001     1   101  1001
#  3 x1         2     2   102  1002
#  4 x2       103     3   103  1003
#  5 x1         4     4   104  1004
#  6 x3      1005     5   105  1005
#  7 x3      1006     6   106  1006
#  8 x2       107     7   107  1007
#  9 x2       108     8   108  1008
# 10 x3      1009     9   109  1009
```