# How can I replace values in one column with values from another out of several options, when the first column contains the name of the other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace

Say I have the table below. I want to replace the value in the column "nameselect" with the respective value from either "name_01" or "name_02". Which of these columns should be chosen is indicated by the original value in "nameselect". As a result, I want "nameselect" to contain just names - in this case, Ann and Claire. I'd also be ok with a solution creating a new column with the names. How do I best go about that?
In my actual data, there's more name columns, so ideally nothing that involves copy-pasting every possible column name. I should also mention that it should work even when there are NAs in "nameselect"

```
| nameselect | name_01        | name_02

| --------   | -------------- |-------------- |

| name_01    | Ann            |Bernie         |

| name_02    | Beth           |Claire         |
```

With dplyr this works, but not when there are NAs:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(result = get(nameselect)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Any way I can adapt this solution to work despite NAs?

Comment: `... %>% mutate(selectedName = ifelse(nameselect == "name_01", name_01, name_02)` or similar is just one option for the specific case you describe.  You can nest `ifelse`s to take account of `NA` if necessary.  or use `case_when` - which is probably a better option of the selection becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple columns, in which case a one-liner general solution using only base R would be:

```r
within(df, nameselect <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), \(i) df[i, df$nameselect[i]]))
#>   nameselect name_01 name_02
#> 1        Ann     Ann  Bernie
#> 2     Claire    Beth  Claire
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works considering you only have two columns

`df[,'nameselect']=ifelse(df[,'nameselect']=='name_01',df[,'name_01'],df[,'name_01'])`

Answer (score 0):

As Limey said, it's quite straightforward:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    nameselect = ifelse(nameselect == "name_01", name_01, name_02))

# or
df$nameselect <- ifelse(df$nameselect == "name_01", df$name_01, df$name_02)

# or 
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(nameselect = get(nameselect))

# or 
df$nameselect <- map_vec(seq_along(df$nameselect), ~ df[[df$nameselect[.x]]][.x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this solution to a similar issue, [R Lookup values of a column defined by another column's values in mutate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678405/r-lookup-values-of-a-column-defined-by-another-columns-values-in-mutate) works with case_when even with NAs. Thanks for the suggestion!

```
x <- switch_cols <- function(var) {
  
  vals <- unique(var)
  
  name <- deparse(substitute(var))
  
  formulae <- lapply(
    sprintf("%s == '%s' ~ %s", name, vals, vals), 
    as.formula, 
    env = parent.frame()
  )
  
  case_when(!!!formulae)
  
}

df %>% 
  mutate(result = switch_cols(nameselect))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is vectorised base R method which will work for any number of columns.

```
df$result <- df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)), match(df$nameselect, names(df)))]

df
#  nameselect name_01 name_02 result
#1    name_01     Ann  Bernie    Ann
#2    name_02    Beth  Claire Claire
```

We create a matrix of row/column pair to subset from dataframe using `cbind` where `seq(nrow(df))` gives the row numbers and `match(df$nameselect, names(df))` gives the column number to subset.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(nameselect = c("name_01", "name_02"), name_01 = c("Ann", 
"Beth"), name_02 = c("Bernie", "Claire")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```